# Any idea to have the jwt in spring boot grpc project

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, grpc

Currently, I am using [`yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter`](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter) project to implement the grpc in spring-boot project.

Any idea to have the `jwt` in the grpc for authentication?

I have the following code, this only work when the client does not have the authentication.

Not sure how to revise it.

### Clent Configuration

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${auth.token}")
    private String token;

    @Bean
    public StubTransformer call() {
        return (name, stub) -> {
            if ("local-grpc-server".equals(name)) {
                return stub.withCallCredentials(CallCredentialsHelper.bearerAuth(token)); // remove this line, the request be passed.
            }
            return stub;
        };
    }

}
```

### Server Configuration & Impementation

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "roles";

    private final JwtProperties jwtProperties;

    @Getter
    private NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    private String secretKey;

    public JwtTokenProvider(JwtProperties jwtProperties) {
        this.jwtProperties = jwtProperties;
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(jwtProperties.getSignKey().getBytes());
        this.jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(stringToSecretKey(secretKey)).build();
    }

    public SecretKey stringToSecretKey(String secret) {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
    }

    public String createToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        if (!authorities.isEmpty()) {
            claims.put(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + this.jwtProperties.getExpireTimeAsSec() * 1000);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, this.secretKey)
                .compact();

    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        Jwt jwt = null;
        try {
            jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(token);
        } catch (JwtException e) {
            throw new InvalidJwtAuthenticationException("Expired or invalid JWT token");
        }

        Object authoritiesClaim = jwt.getClaims().get(AUTHORITIES_KEY);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authoritiesClaim == null ? AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES
                : AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authoritiesClaim.toString());

        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
    }

    public boolean validateToken(Jwt token) {
        try {
            OAuth2TokenValidatorResult result = JwtValidators.createDefault().validate(token);
            return !result.hasErrors();
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new InvalidJwtAuthenticationException("Expired or invalid JWT token");
        }
    }

}
```

**createToken**: generate the token.

```java
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    private static final Map<String, UserDetails> allUsers = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        allUsers.put("pkslow", new UserDetailsImpl("pkslow", passwordEncoder.encode("123456"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));
        allUsers.put("user", new UserDetailsImpl("user", passwordEncoder.encode("123456"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    }

    public Optional<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(allUsers.get(username));
    }
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository users;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return users.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username: " + username + " not found"));
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(
            final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {

        final DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider) {
        final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(daoAuthenticationProvider);
        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }

    @Bean
    GrpcAuthenticationReader authenticationReader(final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        final List<GrpcAuthenticationReader> readers = new ArrayList<>();
        BearerAuthenticationReader reader = new BearerAuthenticationReader(accessToken -> jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(accessToken));
        readers.add(reader);
        return new CompositeGrpcAuthenticationReader(readers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, create a `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` and replace `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with `JwtAuthenticationConverter`.

It's work for me!

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter) {

        final JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider(final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter, final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder) {

        final JwtAuthenticationProvider provider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder);
        provider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider) {
        final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }

    @Bean
    GrpcAuthenticationReader authenticationReader() {
        return new BearerAuthenticationReader(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken::new);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(final JwtProperties jwtProperties) {
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(jwtProperties.getSignKey().getBytes(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(originalKey).build();
    }

}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "roles";

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Object authoritiesClaim = jwt.getClaims().get(AUTHORITIES_KEY);

        return authoritiesClaim == null ? AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES : AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authoritiesClaim.toString());
    }

}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "roles";

    private final JwtProperties jwtProperties;

    private final String secretKey;

    public JwtTokenProvider(JwtProperties jwtProperties) {
        this.jwtProperties = jwtProperties;
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(jwtProperties.getSignKey().getBytes());

    }

    public String createToken(Authentication authentication) {

        String username = authentication.getName();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        if (!authorities.isEmpty()) {
            claims.put(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(joining(",")));
        }

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + this.jwtProperties.getExpireTimeAsSec());

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, this.secretKey)
                .compact();

    }


}
```